# adding multiple lists into one column DataFrame pandas

Tags: pandas

```
l = {'col1': [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = l)

     col1
0   [1, 2, 3]
1   [4, 5, 6]
```

Desired output:

```
  col1
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
```

Comment: you can change the input to continuous list `l = {'col1': sum([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]],[])}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is `explode`

```
df.explode('col1')
  col1
0    1
0    2
0    3
1    4
1    5
1    6
```

Comment: My first time seeing `.explode`, nice!

Comment: Nice. Thanks @YO and BEN_W

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to flatten the list of lists:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd 

l = {'col1': [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ravel(*l.values()),columns=l.keys())

>>> df
   col1
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     6
```

Comment: Thanks, @anky_91. As you can see I prefer using numpy here, too, but understand how some might not want the additional import.

Comment: pandas operates on numpy so for that use case `pd.np` should work `pd.DataFrame(pd.np.concatenate(*l.values()),columns=l.keys())` , but i see what you mean :)

Comment: Thank you very much @bernie